# Replace the first occurence of string that is not between quote tags in PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

I want to replace the first occurence of a string ("[TOREPLACE]") in a vbulletin forum post, but only if that string is not surrounded by bbcode quote tags.

My code:

```
if($firstpos = strpos($post['pagetext'], '[TOREPLACE]') !== false){

    //check for quote
    if($quote_start = strpos($post['pagetext'], '[QUOTE') !== false && $quote_end = strpos($post['pagetext'], '[/QUOTE]') !== false){
        //quote found
        //check if quote starts before egg
        if($quote_start < $firstpos && $firstpos < $quote_end){

            //don't replace, because the string that is to be replace is in between quotes
        }
    }

    $post['pagetext_html'] = preg_replace('~\[TOREPLACE\]~i', '<img src="/src.jpg" border="0" />', $post['pagetext_html'], 1);

}
```

I would have to loop this to find the first occurence of the string that is not between quotes.
This quote check is tedious and not very elegant. Does anybody know of a better algorithm to do the above?

Algorithm: *"If quotes in post - find and replace the first occurence that is not between quote tags. If no quotes, replace the first occurence."*

Maybe I could add all this to the pre_match. The quotes are optional, though, and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Another option is `preg_replace_callback` to capture the quote ranges *and* (with `|` alternative) the tag thing, and then differentiate in the callback depending on the incoming matches array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is slightly more elegant and doesn't break on multiple pieces of quoted text:

```
// for clarity, START and END are used instead of the actual (un)quote pattern

$input = "test text START quoted text END more text START quoted again END.";
$parts = preg_split("/(START.+?END)/",$input,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

// $parts is an array containing quoted parts at odd indexes
print_r($parts);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test text 
    [1] => START quoted text END
    [2] =>  more text 
    [3] => START quoted again END
    [4] => .
)
```

Then loop over the `$parts` and only change the even indexes. After that:

```
$output = implode($parts);
```